# How do I set some List<Account> fields from a List<AggregateResult>?

Tags: apex, map, aggregateresult

I am learning Salesforce and Apex and I got the following task:
whenever an opportunity is updated or created, calculate the related accounts total number of opportunities and total sum of those opportunities. I already created the 2 fields for that on the Account object.

I can calculate these fields, but I don't know how do I combine my List and List objects to update those 2 fields in the Account objects.

this is how I get my List collection:

`List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id, Total_Opportunities__c, Total_Sum_Opportunities__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accIds];`

this is how I calculate for the above 2 fields (Total_Opportunities__c, Total_Sum_Of_Opportunities__c)

```
List<AggregateResult> accsWithOpps = [SELECT AccountId, COUNT(Id)SumOfOpps, SUM(Amount)SumOfAmount FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId IN :accIds GROUP BY AccountId];
```

now how do I iterate over the AggregateResults or over the Accounts to set the Account.Total_Opportunities__c and Account.Total_Sum_Of_Opportunities__c fields to the AggregateResult.SumOfOpps and AggregateResult.SumOfAmount fields.

this is how my AggregateResult object looks like

```
(
AggregateResult:{AccountId=0013z00002PnrrXAAR, SumOfOpps=1, SumOfAmount=235000.0}, AggregateResult:{AccountId=0013z00002PnrrbAAB, SumOfOpps=10, SumOfAmount=3440000.0}
)
```

Now, I am probably missing a crucial bit of coding concept here, please do let me know where I should improve in order to understand and learn how to solve such challenges.
thanks

Comment: This would be better to solve with roll-up summaries, as we have master-detail relationship between Account and Opportunity.

Comment: the first part of my challenge/task was that and I did 2 roll-up summary fields to calculate those, but I guess the dev asked me solve it with soql/apex because there is a limit on how many roll-up summary fields you can use. and he also wanted me to improve while learning how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Just iterate through the collection, assign accounts to the list and update it.

```
List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
List<AggregateResult> accsWithOpps = [SELECT AccountId, COUNT(Id)SumOfOpps, SUM(Amount)SumOfAmount FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId IN :accIds GROUP BY AccountId];
for (AggregateResult ar : accsWithOpps) {
    accountsToUpdate.add(
            new Account(
                    id = (Id) ar.get('Id'),
                    Total_Opportunities__c = Integer.valueOf(res.get('SumOfOpps')),
                    Total_Sum_Opportunities__c = Decimal.valueOf(res.get('SumOfAmount'))
            )
    );
}
update accountsToUpdate;
```

Comment: oh, I didn't think of this. so when you instantiate a new Account object inside the loop, that wont actually create a new record because the specified id is the id of an already existing Account record. correct?

Comment: yes, you are correct

Comment: @Hunor That is correct. You only get a new record if you use the `insert` dml statement (and it'd complain if you tried to insert a record that already has an Id). Using the SObject constructor like this (to set an Id, so you can update a record) is a convenient way to avoid a query (and queries are our most precious resource on the Salesforce platform).

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. However, I would retrieve accounts to Map:

```
Map<Id, Account> accs = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Total_Opportunities__c, Total_Sum_Opportunities__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accIds]);
```

Then you should iterate through your AggregateResult list, get retrieved values by set labels (1st example in this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm)) and set it to respecting field in account:

```
for (AggregateResult res : [SELECT AccountId, COUNT(Id)SumOfOpps, SUM(Amount)SumOfAmount FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId IN :accIds GROUP BY AccountId]) {
    Id accountId = (Id) res.get('AccountId');
    if (accs.containsKey(accountId)) {
        accs.get(accountId).Total_Opportunities__c = (Integer) res.get('SumOfOpps');
        accs.get(accountId).Total_Sum_Opportunities__c = (Decimal) res.get('SumOfAmount');
    }
}
```

Comment: this makes sense. will try it. thank you!

Comment: +1 for the explanation and documentation link, though the first query on Accounts is unnecessary (use the SObject constructor to set the Id of a new Account instance, and you can use that instance in an `update` just fine)